# ich, der ich seit 20 Jahren "meinem Volke" or "seinem Volke" diene? (Questions about pronoun antecedents & relative clause)

Tags: grammar, translation

Question 1: I found the clause "ich, der ich seit 20 Jahren seinem Volke diene" in my textbook. The book says that its English translation is "I, who have been serving my people for 20 years". Why *seinem Volke* for *my people*, not *meinem Volke*? Is the English translation wrong? If the translation and grammar are totally right, can you show me some similar examples?

Question 2: I read in my textbook that if the antecedent is first or second personal pronoun, the pronoun (antecedent) is repeated in the relative clause, as follows:

- *du, **der/die du** ja nicht alles wissen kannst.*
- *für mich, **die ich** noch gar nicht ordentlich lesen konnte.*

Is that rule applied only to *ich* and *du*? What about *er*, *sie*, *wir*, *ihr* and *Sie*? I'd like you to choose the right, natural one in the pairs below in bold. (I've improvised the sentences, so there can be some mistakes. Your correction would be appreciated.):

- *Das Geschenk ist für sie, **die sie / die** morgen Geburtstag hat.*
- *Wir, **die wir / die** arm sind, haben immer Hunger.*
- *Für euch, **die ihr / die** so weit weg wohnt*
- *Er, **der er / der** alles weiß, ist weggegangen.*

Comment: Please avoid to write more than one question in a single post. This will help to keep topics clear in the long run. Thank you.

Comment: Ohne Kontext vermute ich, dass es im Text eine dritte Person existiert, deren Volk die erste Person dient, und dass es möglicherweise nicht deren Volk ist, sondern eben das des anderen. Wieso beginnt das Beispiel mit einem kleinen "i" - wie beginnt denn der Satz?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Q1:
The German sentence and the English translation don't match.

> "ich, der ich seit 20 Jahren seinem Volke diene"

is possible, but it means

> "I, who have been serving **his** people for 20 years".

Here, the speaker serves someone else's people.

Your intuition is right. In order to express that the speaker serves his own people, it is:

> "ich, der ich seit 20 Jahren **meinem** Volke diene"
>
> "I, who have been serving my people for 20 years".

---

Q2: Relative pronouns are inherently third person in German, hence:

> Das Geschenk ist für sie, **die** morgen Geburtstag hat.
>
> Er, **der** alles weiß, ist weggegangen.

"Wir" and "Ihr" are first and second person, respectively. Therefore, the rule you mention counts for them, too:

> Wir, **die wir** arm sind, haben immer Hunger.
>
> Für euch, **die ihr** so weit weg wohnt

Comment: Here's the [canoo.net link](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemPers.html?lang=de#Anchor-49575) to second your answer to Q2. And [here in English](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemPers.html?lang=en#Anchor-49575)

Comment: Shouldn't it be "meinem Volk"? Why would you use Volke?

Comment: @Lars Pötter: Because the old form is used in the original translation as well, I would guess. (And it is fitting, since no-one would say a sentence like this today.)

Comment: I missed out this one: does Sie, formal polite second-person pronoun, also follow the rule? For example, "Das Geschenk ist für Sie, die Sie morgen Geburtstag haben." is right?

Comment: @Em1 According to the linked page, it seems if the first/second person pronoun in the relative clause is left out, not only the verb but other elements in the clause change in third person. When the subject "ich" in the relative clause of "Ich, der/die ich mich nie geweigert habe" is omitted, the reflexive object "mich" turns into "sich", not to mention the verb (habe→hat). Likewise, I think.. if I leave out the second "ich" in "ich, der ich seit 20 Jahren seinem Volke diene", "seinem Volke" can have the same meaning with "meinem Volke". But I'm not sure. What do you and everyone else think?

Comment: @Jin I'm not sure if I understand. Do you mean to change "ich, der ich seit 20J. meinem Volk diene" to "ich, der seit 20j seinem Volk dient", or "ich, der ich mich nie geweigert habe" to "ich, der sich nie geweigert hat"? - If yes, note that you have to change "meinem" to "seinem" if you do so but if it's already "seinem" in the first place, it's still "seinem" because you referring to someone else's country.

Comment: @Em1 You exactly answered my question. You mean if "ich" is taken out of the relative clause, the verb and reflexive pronouns have to be changed according to "der" or "die", right? Then, can "seinem Volk" in "ich, der seit 20J. seinem Volk dient" be interpreted in two ways, depending on the context: "my people" or "his people" (only if it was originally there in the first place)?

Comment: @Jin You got it. It's ambiguous then if you don't have any context. But in continuous text you should get the necessary information to figure out whom "seinem" is referring to. "Der Kaiser von China kehrte mir den Rücken zu. Und ich, der 20 Jahre seinem Volke gedient hat, stehe nun mit leeren Händen da." - "Ich, der Kaiser von China und der 20 Jahre seinem Volke gedient hat, überlasse meinem Sohn den Thron."

Comment: @Em1 Thanks for the examples. I think the "ich" in the first one is a person who works for the Kaiser and the "ich" in the second one the Kaiser himself. Therefore the first "seinem Volke" refers to his people, and the second one to "my people". Am I right?

Comment: @Jin Exactly. That's correct.

Answer (score -1):

Question 1: The translation is wrong. "seinem Volke" is clearly not my people.

Question2: The rule applys to all. So it is :

sie, die sie

Wir, die wir

euch, die ihr

Er, der er

Comment: "Er, der er" and "sie, die sie" are wrong.

Comment: @Em1: Not completely impossible, but unusual and highly marked. - I'm missing "der Sie" etc. from the answers so far.